# Как полностью переписать json файл через php?

Tags: php, json

Как полностью  переписать json файл через php ? Мне нужно через php  перезаписать все данные в существующем json файле. По сути просто заменить весь json внутри.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)** - чтобы взять всё содержимое файла

**[file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)** - пишет данные в файл

**[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)** - переведёт ассоциативный массив в json строку

**[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)** - раскодирует json строку в ассоциативный массив